# How to Refactor this simple Ruby algorithm

Tags: ruby, algorithm, refactoring

Ok, I have this ruby script which opens a file and passes each line to the **line_parser** method. This method simply changes tabs for a couple of spaces. Here it is:

```
$lines = []

def line_parser(line)   
    line.gsub! /\t/, '  '
    $lines[$lines.length] = line
end

f = File.open(ARGV[0], 'r').each { |line| line_parser(line) }
f.close

f = File.open(ARGV[0], 'w')
$lines.each { |line| f.puts line}
f.close
```

As you can see it has two loops; **one loop** to iterate over the lines of text inside the file an place them inside of an array. And the other loop writes the file all over again with the *new* lines from the recently created array.

My question is simple I think:
**How can I refactor this snippet so that I do all the steps described above inside one loop only?**

I know it can be done, I just have not been able to do it with my current ruby knowledge.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question gives an alternative: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5452781/edit-each-line-in-a-file-in-ruby, which is to write a temp file then overwrite the input file, rather than looping through the lines again.  Although if you simply looking for a simple way to do this (not just a better ruby way), i believe `sed -i 's/\t/  /g' yourfile` would do the trick.

Comment: this kind of question would be better off at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
out = ""
File.open(ARGV[0], "r+") do |f|
  f.each do |line|
    out << line.gsub(/\t/, '  ')
  end
  f.pos=0
  f.print out
end
```

This just iterates over the file once but it still has to cache the file in a string before finally writing it to the file. If you want to avoid caching you will have to write to a temporary file first. Once done reading/writing you would simply delete the old file and replace it with the new temporary file by renaming it.

Comment: Your code works pretty well, a million times better than what I did. :) However, I'm just wondering.. Could this be done w/o temp. Files or Strings or Arrays at all? (just wondering..)

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/usr/local/bin/ruby -w

src = File.read(ARGV[0])

File.open(ARGV[0], 'w') { | io |
  src.each_line { | line |
    io << line.gsub(/\t/, '  ')
  }
}
```

Please note that this is actually cheated. Reading the whole file is in fact a loop.
But since you are reading and then writing to the same file, I doubt you can avoid having 
2 loops (one for reading and one for writing).

Comment: Looks good, very Idiomatic. Could you explain the io parameter for the block of the File.open ?
Thank you very much for your answer !

Comment: @user766388: It's the Ruby way to express `io = File.open(...); io << ...; io.close`.

Answer (score 1):

Can we use rubygems?

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'facets/file'

# Version 1
File.write('outfile', File.read('infile').tr("\t", ' '))

# Version 2
File.rewrite('inoutfile') { |str| str.tr("\t", ' ') }
```

Comment: I could use anything I guess. that seems like an interesting solution.
What packages am I actually pulling to the file when I do: require 'rubygems' ? pardon my ignorance. Thanks

Comment: @user - Rubygems is the de-facto package management system for ruby. When you require rubygems you're simply loading or activating the package management system. After this is done individual packages can then be activated with `require`, like I do here with the `facets` package. To learn more and search or browse available packages go here: http://rubygems.org/

Comment: That was incredibly useful to me. Nicely explained, thank you very much! I really need these little insights into the language now.