# How to edit every x amount of lines in txtfile in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to change something in every other line in a text file using Ruby (and some text files I need to change something every third line and so on.)

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5452781/edit-each-line-in-a-file-in-ruby) helpful for iterating over every line, but I specifically need help making changes every x amount of lines.

The `###` is the part I'm having trouble with (the iterating over x amount of lines.)

```rb
text = File.open('fr.txt').read
clean = ### .sub("\n", " ");
new = File.new("edit_fr.txt", "w")
new.puts clean
new.close
```

Comment: post what you've done so far and ask a more specific Q

Comment: Do you need a single line every so many lines? Like every third line, or every fourth line? Or would you need say two lines then skip a line, then two lines, etc.?

Comment: I need to combine every two lines:

line1 /n line2 /n line3 /n line would become line1 space line2 /n line3 space line4

Comment: Try the answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use modulus division as below where `n` refers to the nth line you want to process and `i` refers to the 0-based index for the file lines. Using those two values, modulo math provides the remainder from integer division which will be 0 whenever the 1-based index (`i+1`) is multiple of `n`.

```rb
n = 3 # modify every 3rd line

File.open('edit_fr.txt','w') do |f|               # Open the output file
  File.open('fr.txt').each_with_index do |line,i| # Open the input file
    if (i+1) % n == 0                             # Every nth line
      f.print line.chomp                          # Remove newline
    else                                          # Every non-nth line
      f.puts line                                 # Print line
    end
  end
end
```

More info is available on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation

> In computing, the modulo operation finds the remainder after division of one number by another (sometimes called modulus).
>
> Given two positive numbers, a (the dividend) and n (the divisor), a modulo n (abbreviated as a mod n) is the remainder of the Euclidean division of a by n. For instance, the expression "5 mod 2" would evaluate to 1 because 5 divided by 2 leaves a quotient of 2 and a remainder of 1, while "9 mod 3" would evaluate to 0 because the division of 9 by 3 has a quotient of 3 and leaves a remainder of 0; there is nothing to subtract from 9 after multiplying 3 times 3. (Note that doing the division with a calculator will not show the result referred to here by this operation; the quotient will be expressed as a decimal fraction.)

Answer (score 1):

```
every_other = 2

File.open('data.txt') do |f|
  e = f.each
  target_line = nil

  loop do
    every_other.times do
      target_line = e.next
    end

    puts target_line
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You wish to write each line of an input file to an output file, but you want to modify each `nth` line of the input file before writing it, beginning with the first line of the file.

Suppose we have defined a method `modify`, which accepts a line of text as its argument and returns a modified string. Then you can do it like this:

```
def modify_and_write(in_fname, out_fname, n)
  enum = Array.new(n) { |i| i.zero? ? :process : :skip }.cycle
  f = File.open(out_fname, 'w')
  IO.foreach(in_fname) do |line|
    (line = process(line)) if enum.next == :process
    f.puts(line)
  end
  f.close
end
```

I'm reading one line at a time (rather using [IO#readlines](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/IO.html#method-c-readlines)) to read the entire file into an array) so that it will work with files of any size.

Suppose:

```
n = 3
```

The key here is the enumerator:

```
enum = Array.new(n) { |i| i.zero? ? :process : :skip }.cycle
  #=> #<Enumerator: [:process, :skip, :skip]:cycle> 
enum.next #=> :process 
enum.next #=> :skip 
enum.next #=> :skip 
enum.next #=> :process 
enum.next #=> :skip 
enum.next #=> :skip 
enum.next #=> :process 
enum.next #=> :skip
...
```

**Edit:** after answering I noticed the OP's comment: `I need to combine every two lines: line1 /n line2 /n line3 /n line would become line1 space line2 /n line3 space line4`, which is not consistent with "I'm trying to change something in every other line in a text file". To address the specific requirement, my solution could be modified as follows:

```
def combine_lines(in_fname, out_fname, n)
  enum = Array.new(n) { |i| (i==n-1) ? :write : :read }.cycle
  f = File.open(out_fname, 'w')
  combined = []
  IO.foreach(in_fname) do |line|
    combined << line.chomp
    if enum.next == :write
      f.puts(combined.join(' '))
      combined.clear
    end
  end
  f.puts(combined.join(' ')) if combined.any?
  f.close
end
```

Let's try it:

```
text =<<_
Now is
the time
for all
good
Rubyists
to do
something
other
than
code.
_

File.write('in',text)
combine_lines('in', 'out', 3)
puts File.read('out')
  # Now is the time for all
  # good Rubyists to do
  # something other than
  # code.
```

You could also use a regex, as @Stefan has done, which would be my preference for less-than-humongous files. Here's another regex implementation:

```
def combine_lines(in_fname, out_fname, n)
  IO.write(out_fname,
    IO.read(in_fname)
      .scan(/(?:.*?\n){1,#{n}}/)
      .map { |s| s.split.join(' ') }
    )
end

combine_lines('in', 'out', 3)
puts File.read('out')
  # Now is the time for all
  # good Rubyists to do
  # something other than
  # code.
```

We could write the above regex with the final `/` changed to `/x` to include comments:

```
r = /
 (?:       # begin a non-capture group
  .*?      # match any number of any character, non-greedily
  \n       # match (the first, because of non-greedily) end-of-line
  )        # end the non-capture group
  {1,#{n}} # match between 1 and n of the preceding non-capture group
/x
```

`{1,#{n}}` is "greedy" in the sense that it will match as many lines as possible, up to `n`. If the number of lines were always a multiple of `n`, we could instead write `{{#n}}`, meaning match `n` non-capture groups (i.e., `n` lines). However, if the number of lines is not a multiple of `n` (as in my example above), we need `{1,#{n}}` to match the last few lines in the last non-capture group.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do it with just a regex:

**EDIT**

OK, I knew I could do this with `each_slice` and a simple regex:

```
def chop_it(file,num)
#file name and the number of lines to join
  arr = []
#create an empty array to hold the lines we create
  File.open(file) do |f|
#open your file into a `do..end` block, it closes automatically for you
    f.each_slice(num) do |slice|
#get an array of lines equal to num
      arr << slice.join(' ').gsub!(/\n/, '') + "\n"
#join the lines with ' ', then remove all the newlines and tack one
# on the end, adding the resulting line to the array.
    end
  end
  arr.join
#join all of the lines back into one string that can be sent to a file.
end
```

And there you have it, simple and flexible. Just enter file name and the number of lines you want reduced down to one line. i.e. if you want every two lines joined, `chop_it('data.txt',2)`. Every three? `chop_it('data.txt,3)`.

** old answer **

```
old_text = File.read(data.txt)

new_text = old_text.gsub(/(?:(^.*)\n(^.*\n))/i,'\1 \2')
```

The regex matches the first line up to "\n" and the second line up to and including "\n". The substitution returns the two matches with a space between them.

```
"this is line one\nthis is line two\n this is line three\nthis is line four]n"
\1 = "this is line one"
\2 = "this is line two\n"
'\1 \2' = "this is line one this is line two\n"
```

This regex will also handle removing every other blank line in successive blank lines

Answer (score 0):

```
new = File.new("edit_fr.txt", "w")
File.readlines("test.txt").each_slice(2) do |batch| # or each_slice(3) etc
  new.puts batch.map(&:chomp).join(" ")
end
new.close
```

Answer (score 0):

> I need to combine every two lines: line1 /n line2 /n line3 /n line would become line1 space line2 /n line3 space line4

You could [`read`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/IO.html#method-c-read) the entire file into a string, use [`gsub!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/String.html#method-i-gsub-21) and [`with_index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index) to replace every *n*th newline with space and [`write`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/IO.html#method-c-write) the replaced content to a new file:

```
content = IO.read('fr.txt')
content.gsub!("\n").with_index(1) { |m, i| (i % 2).zero? ? m : ' ' }
IO.write('edit-fr.txt', content)
```

Input `fr.txt`:

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
```

Output `edit-fr.txt`:

```
line1 line2
line3 line4
```

Comment: Very inventive! After seeing yours, I offered a variant.

Comment: ...or: `counter = Array.new(n) { |i| :replace if i<n-1 }.cycle; 
content.gsub!("\n") { |m| (counter.next==:replace) ? ' ' : m }`.