# How to append columns to existing CSV using Ruby 2.2.2

Tags: ruby, csv

**Edit: I don't need to use the same file. A new file can be created. What I do need is the result to contain the same columns and rows as in the original plus the new columns, but in the same order.**

I've been trying to append columns to an existing CSV file with Ruby but I'm getting an error that I don't understand it. Here's my code:

```
CSV.foreach("test.csv", "a+") do | row |
c = Curl::Easy.perform("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=#{row[1]},#{row[0]}&sensor=false")
result = JSON.parse(c.body_str)
if result['status'] != 'OK'
    sleep(5)
else
    row << result['results'][0]['formatted_address']
    result['results'][0]['address_components'].each do | w |
        row << w['short_name']
    end
end
```

end

On the `CSV.foreach...` part I've tried `CSV.foreach('file.csv', 'a+')`, `CSV.foreach('file.csv', 'wb')`, `CSV.foreach('file.csv', 'a')` and nothing seemed to work.

Then it dawned on me that maybe I should be using `open` instead:

```
        file = CSV.open('test.csv', 'wb')
    file.each do | csv |
        c = Curl::Easy.perform("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=#{row[1]},#{row[0]}&sensor=false")
        result = JSON.parse(c.body_str)
        if result['status'] != 'OK'
            sleep(5)
        else
            row << result['results'][0]['formatted_address']
            result['results'][0]['address_components'].each do | w |
                row << w['short_name']
            end
        end
    end
```

But that didn't work either.

What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: `row` is an internal representation read from the CSV file. The modification to it won't affect the original CSV source. You need to open another CSV file for write, and write the row to that file after modification. Is this what you're missing?

Comment: I thought there would be a way to modify the current document though. On the docs it seems that's the case but I couldn't figure it out for sure...

Comment: Editing files in place seems to be already covered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5452781 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4397412 with a couple of good answers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Edit each line in a file in Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5452781/edit-each-line-in-a-file-in-ruby)

Comment: But both answers address editing a file rather than a CSV. I'm using the CSV class, wouldn't it be different approach?

Comment: Other point is that I don't need to use the same file. I can create another file, but it got to be based off the initial file but with the new columns appended.

Comment: Oh I see! In that case, please disregard my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try opening the file with a different mode?

Looks like this is what you are looking for:

```
CSV.open('test.csv', 'r+') do |row|
  row << ['existing_header1','existing_header2','new_header']
end
```

This will in fact overwrite your first line for the one you just specified. It works because 'r+' reads from the beginning of the file, and overwrites any existing rows as it goes through the file. But in this case you just need to change the first one :)

Here's a list of useful modes you can use to open a file. Cheers.

> "r" -- read only from the beginning of the file
>
> "r+" -- read/write from the beginning of the file
>
> "w" -- write only, overwriting the entire existing file or creating a new one if none existed
>
> "w+" -- read/write, overwriting the entire existing file or creating a new one if none existed
>
> "a" -- write only, starting at the end of existing file or creating a new one if none existed
>
> "a+" -- read/write, starting at the end of existing file or creating a new one if none existed

Source: [Opening modes](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html)

Comment: This does not work. It does not replace the first line. It only replaces the first characters.